# Datepicker date not changing after selecting a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using a jquery for my  datepicker to update certain dates through a modal form.  Date change fine when modal is open and close when after the page loads however when I re-open  the same or another form the date is not updating/changing in the input box. not sure what could be the issue.

```js
jQuery("#date2").datepicker();
jQuery("#date1").datepicker();

// dialog form is triggered through ajax 
var Edit = function (id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Exposure/EditSession",
            data: { Id: id},
            success: function (response) {
                $("#myModalBodydiv").html(response),
                $("#myModalForm").modal("show"),
                $("#myModalForm").appendTo("body");
            }
        })
    }
```

```html
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></scrip>

<--layout.cshtml -->
<body>
    <partial name="_Scripts" />
</body>

<-- button edit to trigger the dialog form in Index.cshtml -->
<div class="form-button-action">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-lg" id="Edit" onclick="Edit(@item.id)">/button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModalForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodydiv" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<-- dialog modal form that contains the datepicker, partialEdit.cshtml -->
<form method="post" asp-action="Edit">
  <div class="mb-4">
    <label for="squareInput">Date of Birth</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="date2" asp-for="dateofbirth">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-4">
    <label for="squareInput">Plan Effective Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="date1" asp-for="planeffectivedate">
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer no-bd">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: I've added jquery to your snippet (and removed the `<script>` tag from the js box).  Please add any other script src= includes, such as whichever datapicker you happend to be using -is it [jquery-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui/info)?  Or bootstrap?  Or another of the 1000s of datepickers?   Also, please update the snippet so that it *demonstrates the issue* (see [mcve]) - as it is you mention a dialog, but there's no dialog in the code.

Comment: Hello @freedomn. Im only using the datepicker in the modal form as shown in the sample. It works fine at first after the page has loaded though when I select another item e.g I want to edit the date, the date doesn't change as soon the Date is selected

Comment: Yes, we can see that in your video, but without knowing the details I requested above, it's impossibly to *reproduce* it.   If it can be reproduced, then it's much more likely a solution can be found, but otherwise it's just guess work (especially as different datepickers work differently).

Comment: From the video, it looks like you open the dialog form and it contains the Date Picker. I try to test it on my side by creating the dialog popup and JQuery Date Picker but you could see in my [test result](https://imgur.com/a/yBE3HKU) that the date picker works fine. If possible, please share your sample code to check the issue. It may give a better idea regarding the issue.

Comment: Hi @freedomn, I added some details in the snippet above how I implement the datepicker. hope this helps. appreciaiate your help

Comment: HI @Deepak-MSFT as requested, I updated  the details above that is possible causing the  issue in the Datepicker.

Comment: A quick look at your `<script src` list - you have 2x jquery and you have jquery-ui and bootstrap, which are known to have conflicting methods / css.

Comment: Thanks freedomn, however I'm not sure which one I can remove. I tried to disable each script one at time and by disabling this >> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> date picker doesn't even the other jquery.ui is still active. can you enlighten me which one I can retain and which one I should remove?

Comment: I have try to check your updated code and found that you have posted the partial code and when I run the code nothing happens. If possible, you could try to post a sample that could reproduce the issue on our end. It may help to find the cause of the said issue.

Comment: Hi Deepak.  thank you for the suggestion, here's the entire solution https://github.com/platonv1/Datepicker-Issue. I excluded and disabled unnecessary  modules, methods to easily read the codes. all the scripts is in the Views\Shared\_Scripts.cshtml

Comment: @Veck, I am not able to find `Views\Shared_Scripts.cshtml`. Please see [this image](https://imgur.com/a/KtErGsv). I am not sure whether you forgot to add that file? Further, when I run the project it shows me an error 'SocketException: No such host is known.' on line `@foreach(var item in Model)`.

Comment: Hi Deepak. its insided the Shared folder... sorry for the incorrect path.  this connects to the database reason with the host error

Comment: I would suggest you try to clear the date textboxes when you close the dialog using the code. See whether it gets assigned with the new date when you open the new record. You need to make this test on your side because you have the data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi @Deepak-MSFT I tried to clear but no luck. here's the updated repository with no database dependency https://github.com/platonv1/DP1

Comment: @Veck, looks like the latest link you shared is broken. Could you please check the link and correct it?

Comment: Hello @Deepak-MSFT forget to share in public.  Should see the entire solution now

Comment: @Veck, thanks for sharing the project sample. I am able to reproduce the issue with it. I try to make some tests with your project. I try to reinitialize the date picker. I remove it and readded it while again opening the dialog but the issue persists. I will do some more tests and let you know about it. If the issue persists then you could provide feedback to JQuery Datepicker.

Comment: Appereciate @Deepak-MSFT. yeah same thing i did. its kinda weird and i believed it has something to do with boostrap. no worries will try to figure out