# Datepicker not updating date after closing and reopen of modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I have a modal form with a jquery datepicker. Form is displayed from a return partial view. and date change fine when the first form were open  however on the second time the form were opened, nothing happens after changing the date, I don't find any error in the console as I debug which give's me trouble figuring out what could be causing the problem. Below are all the scripts and possible there is a conflict in between those scripts that Im not pretty sure what it is...

[image]

```js
<!--   Core JS Files   -->
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Date Picker  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Scrollbar -->
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>

<!-- Chart JS -->
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/chart.js/chart.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Sparkline -->
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/jquery.sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>

<!-- Chart Circle -->
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/chart-circle/circles.min.js"></script>

<!-- Datatables -->
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Notify -->
@*<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>*@
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- jQuery Vector Maps -->
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>

<!-- Sweet Alert -->
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<!-- Atlantis JS -->
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/atlantis.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<div class="form-button-action">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-lg" id="Edit" onclick="Edit(@item.id)"><a class="fas fa-pencil-alt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit Session"></a></button>
</div>

var Edit = function (id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Exposure/Edit",
            data: { Id: id},
            success: function (response) {
                $("#myModalBodydiv").html(response),
                $('#myModalForm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
                $("#myModalForm").modal("show"),
                $("#myModalForm").appendTo("body");
            }
        })



<--Modal Dialog Form-->
<div class="mb-4">
  <label for="squareInput">Date of Birth</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="birth" asp-for="dateofbirth">
</div>

jQuery("#birth").datepicker();


public IActionResult EditSession(int Id)
{
    return PartialView("_partialViewEdit");
}
```

Comment: Where is the `code snippet` when `clicking on the save button in modal`, could you please share the details so that it can be investigated well.

Comment: Hi @Md Farid, I updated the above code. I suspect its the bootstrap that might be causing the issue. not pretty though

Comment: Is this the same of your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048938/datepicker-date-not-changing-after-selecting-a-date ? Please don't post duplicate questions - if you have more info to add, edit your original question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datepicker date not changing after selecting a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048938/datepicker-date-not-changing-after-selecting-a-date)

Comment: Yes it's the same question though I didn't get answer yet and thouht of posting another one to share the scripts I was using in this project

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.  Delete this one, edit your original question and add whatever new info you have.